# Summarizing Duplicates in Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a pandas Dataframe, containing numbers and strings. Some "ID" exist more than ones. For those I want to sum up the numbers and join the strings with a comma.

```
data = {'ID': ('111', '222', '333', '333'),
        'Text': ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'),
        'Number_1': (1, 2, 3, 4),
        'Number_2': (4, 3, 2, 1)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With the following, I can sum up the numbers of course, but I'm searching for a way to combine the text as well:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID'])['Zahl', 'Zahl_2'].sum().reset_index()
```

The result should be a dataframe with the following content:

```
data = {'ID': ('111', '222', '333'),
        'Text': ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc,ddd'),
        'Number_1': (1, 2, 7),
        'Number_2': (4, 3, 3)}
```

Comment: ```df.groupby("ID").agg(','.join).join(df.groupby("ID").sum())``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use named aggregations with `join` for `Text` column:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg(Text = ('Text', ','.join),
                            Number_1= ('Number_1','sum'),
                            Number_2 =('Number_2', 'sum')
                            ).reset_index() 

print (df)
    ID     Text  Number_1  Number_2
0  111      aaa         1         4
1  222      bbb         2         3
2  333  ccc,ddd         7         3
```

EDIT:

For old pandas versions use:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'Text': ','.join, 
                             'Number_1':'sum',
                             'Number_2': 'sum'}
                            ).reset_index() 

print (df)
    ID     Text  Number_1  Number_2
0  111      aaa         1         4
1  222      bbb         2         3
2  333  ccc,ddd         7         3
```

Comment: I somehow get a TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: @user9092346 - What is your pandas version? Is possible upgrade?